# How do I find how many members from one group are also members of another group?

Tags: python

I am trying to find the number of people of a certain group who appear in other groups. For instance, here is the Pandas dataframe:

```
d = {'name': ['ash', 'psyduck', 'pikachu', 'charizard', 'ash', 'psyduck'], 'group': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'b', 'b', 'a']}
```

Which looks like this:

Ash: a

Psyduck: b

Pikachu: c

Charizard: b

Ash: b

Psyduck: a

I am trying to create a cross tabulation that looks like the following:

```
   a   b    c
a  2   2    0
b  2   3    0
c  0   0    1
```

Essentially, this cross tab shows how many members of group x are also members of group x. For example, there are 2 people who are in group a and b, thus there is a 2 in the intersection of those columns

I have used Pandas cross tab function but it doesn't give the result that I am looking for.

Comment: https://pbpython.com/pandas-crosstab.html

Comment: @AlexHall This doesn't solve my problem. I have tried pandas crosstab in multiple ways but it still does not result in what I am looking for.

Comment: Yes, as OP says, R has a function for solving this called `table`, however I don't find an easy one liner for python. Maybe a combination of group-by and pivot-tables

Comment: This is a starting point if it helps anyhow: `print(df.groupby('name')['group'].apply(list))`

Comment: @stackoverflowusrone It's showing how many members of group x are also members of group x. Ie. there are 2 people who are in group a and b, thus there is a 2 in the intersection of those columnss.

Comment: use `sklearn`? unless you don't want to. nvm

Comment: @CeliusStingher that is very helpful, thank you!

Comment: What's the problem? Have you tried anything, done any research? _I have used Pandas cross tab function but it doesn't give the result that I am looking for._ Where is your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd

d = {'name': ['ash', 'psyduck', 'pikachu', 'charizard', 'ash', 'psyduck'], 'group': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'b', 'b', 'a']}

df = pd.DataFrame(d)
df = df.merge(df, on='name')
print(
  pd.crosstab(df.group_x, df.group_y)
)
```

Output:

```
group_y  a  b  c
group_x         
a        2  2  0
b        2  3  0
c        0  0  1
```

Demo: https://repl.it/@alexmojaki/TragicFrigidConditions

Comment: Nicely done, I have been struggling to find an easy way of doing this, I achieved with like 8 lines, cheers!